# S-Parameters Power amplifier impedance matching

Tags: rf, impedance-matching, power-amplifier, input-impedance, power-output-stage

I recently decided to conceive a 10W class 446MHz amplifier.

I want to be able to amplify a 100mW signal into a 10W, for that i'm going for a two stages amplifier :

SKY65162 to amplify the signal to 1W Then a 2SK3075 to reach 10W approx. Datasheets :

https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/472/SKYS_S_A0006619433_1-2515303.pdf https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/semiconductor/product/mosfets/detail.2SK3075.html

The first amplifier is very well documented in the datasheet, but the second is more tricky. I have this datasheet which describes partly the circuit to make use of the transistor :

[image]

Schematic recommended by the manufacturer This schematic is supposed to describes the circuit required to function at around 500MHz. I was going to use theses values but I thought i could use the S-Parameters provided by Toshiba to make the impedance matching at the input and output.

I've bee searching through internet, lot's of publication, white papers. I even reopened my engineering books to find absolutely nothing.

Toshiba S-Parameters :

```
VAR        vds = 16.0

VAR        id = 0.500

!          REM     DATA    NUMBER = 56

BEGIN      ACDATA

#          HZ      S       MA      R            50

% F        n11x    n11y    n21x    n21y    n12x    n12y    n22x    n22y

450000000  0.880  -173.1   1.546    60.6  0.0193   -22.5   0.817  -176.5
```

**Questions:**

- *Is this even possible?*
- *Does anybody could recommend me a document / method to do this?*

Comment: Have you tried this tool ? https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/AppCAD-Design-Assistant

Comment: Or RFSim99 on same site ... or https://www.electroschematics.com/rfsim99-download/